# Determine the set of positions of $ M$

Tags: complex-numbers

let M be the affix of $Z$ Determine the set of positions of $ M$ when : $$ Z=2\sin(\theta)e^{i({\theta-\frac{\pi}{2}})}  , \ \ \ with  \ \ \ \ \theta \in [0,\pi] $$
I need indication to finding a solution to the exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2 e^{i \left(t-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)} \sin (t)=2 e^{i \left(t-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)} \left(\frac{1}{2} i e^{-i t}-\frac{1}{2} i e^{i t}\right)=1-e^{2 i t},\;t\in[0,\pi]$$
Represents a circle $radius=1$ and center $(0,1)$